# How do I add a tick, timer, clock, or behavior to my scene that runs continuously in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I am trying to write a clock or timer.

```
function ttimer(){
  var options = {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
  };
  var el_ttimer=document.querySelector('#a-ttimer');
  var d = new Date();
  el_ttimer.setAttribute('text', 'text: '+d.toLocaleString("ru", options)+'; font: Droid Sans Mono; size: .77;');
}
setInterval(ttimer, 1000);

<a-entity a-ttimer position="-12 0 -5" id="a-ttimer"></a-entity>
```

How update text smoothly? Timer for example.

How create new primitives in scene smoothly?

Have you best practice for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a component that has the `tick` handler, which will hook into the scene's render loop. https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/core/component.html#tick-time-timedelta

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('timertext', {
  tick: function (time, timeDelta) {
    // ...
    el_ttimer.setAttribute('text', 'text: '+ d.toLocaleString("ru", options) + '; font: Droid Sans Mono; size: .77;');
  }
});

<a-entity timertext text></a-entity>
```

If you want to create a new primitive, use `AFRAME.registerPrimitive`. https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/primitives/#register-a-primitive

```
AFRAME.registerPrimitive('a-ttimer', {
  defaultComponents: {
    timertext: {},
    text: {}
  },

  mappings: {
    text: 'text.text'
  }
});

<a-ttimer text="0"></a-ttimer>
```